# Loop through all properties of a variable. Including complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have the following program that loops through all properties of my variable:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person {Age = 30, Name = "Tony Montana", Mf = new Gender {Male = true,Female = false}};
        var type = typeof(Person);
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} : Value= {2}", property.Name, property.PropertyType, property.GetValue(person, null));
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Mf;
}


 public class Gender
  {
       public bool Male;
       public bool Female;
   }
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
"Age = System.Int32 : Value= 30"
"Name = System.String : Value= Tony Montana"
```

I dont see my complex type person.Mf. How do i  loop through my object person and get the type of person.Mf and the properties of person.Mf (i.e person.Mf.Male etc)? Thanks in advance

Comment: public class Gender
    {
        public bool Male;
        public bool Female;
    }

Comment: In the code you've provided, Gender is a field, not a property (there is no get/set).

Comment: Your `Gender` class is very strange. What if I create `new Gender {Male = true,Female = true}`? I think you should use enum here, or even boolean value.

Comment: This is just a sample of what i'm trying to achieve. I have a web service I call and the results have a bunch of complex types in the object returned. I dont have anycode or docs on where my data is stored in the results, so i want to loop through the object returned and get all  the values. So i wrote this person class as a test

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I thought about commenting on that, but biologically it is possible for an organism to be either both male and female, or neither male or female, so there's some possibility that he needs to support the more general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mf is a field, not a property.  Change it to:

```
public Gender Mf { get; set; }
```

Or, alternatively, use reflection to iterate through all of the public fields (but I think you're better off just making it a property).

Comment: When I made it a property I get the following output:  "Mf = ConsoleApplication1.Gender : Value= ConsoleApplication1.Gender". How do i get the names and values in the Mf object thats encapsulated in my person object?

Comment: You probably want to Override `ToString` in Gender so that it provides a more meaningful string representation.

Comment: This is returning the (default) ToString implementation on your complex object.  Either override ToString, or recursively reflect on complex objects until you are left with only simple objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see it cause it's not a property.

To resolve that issue,

- or define it like a property
- or using reflection recover fields too

  `FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields()`

Comment: I made it a property and tried this, but all i get nothing back

Comment: FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();

            foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} : Value= {2}", fieldInfo.Name, fieldInfo.FieldType, fieldInfo.GetValue(person));
            }